# ABP Update child and parent table in the same function

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, abp

I have a code in .net core 6.0, abp 6.0, trying to make a small web system. I have a table named darbanPrisonerEntry
[Darban Prisoner Entry Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVulL.png)

```
 public class DarbanPrisonerEntry : FullAuditedEntity<long>
{
    public long BiometricId { get; set; }
    public virtual BiometricInfoBase Biometric { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public DateTime AdmissionDate { get; set; }
    public string FatherName { get; set; }
    public bool Prisoner { get; set; }
    public string CNIC { get; set; }
    public string FIRNo { get; set; }
    public long PrisonId { get; set; }
    public List<DabanPrisonerUnderSections> UnderSections { get; set; }
    public long PoliceStationId { get; set; }
    public bool PrisonerAdded { get; set; }
}
```

with a linked table named BiometricInfoBase
[Biometric Info Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOnUE.png)

```
 public class BiometricInfoBase : FullAuditedEntity<long>
{
    public string FrontPic { get; set; }
    public string LeftPic { get; set; }
    public string RightPic { get; set; }
    public string RightThumb { get; set; }
    public string LeftThumb { get; set; }
    public string RightIndex { get; set; }
    public string LeftIndex { get; set; }
}
```

and a child table DabanPrisonerUnderSections
[Daban Prisoner Under Sections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/378nI.png)

```
 public class DabanPrisonerUnderSections : FullAuditedEntity<long>
{
    public long SectionId { get; set; }
    public long DarbanPrisonerEntryId { get; set; }
    public virtual DarbanPrisonerEntry DarbanPrisonerEntry { get; set; }
}
```

When i try insert command it works perfectly, it inserts entries in both the linked tables.
[Insert function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDQ4E.png)

```
 public async Task<CreateEditDarbanPrisonerEntryOutputDto> CreateUpdateDarbanPrisonerEntry(CreateEditDarbanPrisonerEntryInputDto input)
    {
        CreateEditDarbanPrisonerEntryOutputDto response = new CreateEditDarbanPrisonerEntryOutputDto();
        try
        {
            using (_unitOfWorkManager.Current.SetTenantId(AbpSession.TenantId.GetValueOrDefault()))
            {
                if (AbpSession.UserId != null)
                {
                    var darban = _objectMapper.Map<DarbanPrisonerEntry>(input.Data);

                    darban.Id= (await _darbanEntryRepo.InsertAndGetIdAsync(darban));
                    response.IsSuccessful = true;
                    response.Data=_objectMapper.Map<DarbanPrisonerEntryDto>(darban);
                }
                else
                {
                    response.IsSuccessful = false;
                    throw new UserFriendlyException("User not logged in");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new UserFriendlyException(ex.InnerException==null ? ex.Message : ex.InnerException.Message);
        }

        return response;
    }
```

but on update, it only updates the parent table and the linked table isnt updated and the child table gets multiple inserts.
[Update function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsBMT.png)

```
   public async Task<CreateEditDarbanPrisonerEntryOutputDto> CreateUpdateDarbanPrisonerEntry(CreateEditDarbanPrisonerEntryInputDto input)
    {
        CreateEditDarbanPrisonerEntryOutputDto response = new CreateEditDarbanPrisonerEntryOutputDto();
        try
        {
            using (_unitOfWorkManager.Current.SetTenantId(AbpSession.TenantId.GetValueOrDefault()))
            {
                if (AbpSession.UserId != null)
                {
                    var darban = _objectMapper.Map<DarbanPrisonerEntry>(input.Data);

                    darban= (await _darbanEntryRepo.UpdateAsync(darban));
                    response.IsSuccessful = true;
                    response.Data=_objectMapper.Map<DarbanPrisonerEntryDto>(darban);
                }
                else
                {
                    response.IsSuccessful = false;
                    throw new UserFriendlyException("User not logged in");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new UserFriendlyException(ex.InnerException==null ? ex.Message : ex.InnerException.Message);
        }

        return response;
    }
```

even when I try to update the linked table separately
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jFUw.png)

```
    public async Task<CreateEditDarbanPrisonerEntryOutputDto> CreateUpdateDarbanPrisonerEntry(CreateEditDarbanPrisonerEntryInputDto input)
    {
        CreateEditDarbanPrisonerEntryOutputDto response = new CreateEditDarbanPrisonerEntryOutputDto();
        try
        {
            using (_unitOfWorkManager.Current.SetTenantId(AbpSession.TenantId.GetValueOrDefault()))
            {
                if (AbpSession.UserId != null)
                {
                    var darban = _objectMapper.Map<DarbanPrisonerEntry>(input.Data);
                    var biometric = _objectMapper.Map<BiometricInfoBase>(input.Data.Biometric);
                    biometric =await _biometricBaseRepo.UpdateAsync(biometric);
                    darban= (await _darbanEntryRepo.UpdateAsync(darban));
                    response.IsSuccessful = true;
                    response.Data=_objectMapper.Map<DarbanPrisonerEntryDto>(darban);
                }
                else
                {
                    response.IsSuccessful = false;
                    throw new UserFriendlyException("User not logged in");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new UserFriendlyException(ex.InnerException==null ? ex.Message : ex.InnerException.Message);
        }

        return response;
    }
```

i get this error
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leJTv.png)

Comment: Paste code, not screenshots.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi,
Your update approach does not match ABP's approach. Could you check the below URL, please? 
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Tutorials/Part-8?UI=MVC&DB=EF#updateasync